# How to correctly setup folders / files in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am currently starting out in node.js and I am a bit confused with the folder/file setups. Let´s say I have a main folder where all my different projects are located, and those are folders too. Now where do I need to keep my node-modules folder? Also how about the package.json file, do I need that inside each project folder?

Comment: Most of time you have a `node_modules` folder per project/package.

Comment: thank´s. that makes sense as you are using them in each project.

Answer (score 3):

use npm init first 
it will make a package.json file.
Install the dependencies which be stored in Node_modules folder
Now make a folder named Public 
with subfolders assets, css, js, index.html -- the FrontEnd part